# Why registering functions as services in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to understand some basics about angularjs.

Suppose I have a function:

```
function getMyData() {
  //returns some data...
}
```

Why should I register it as a service and not using it directly in a controller?

i.e. why this:

```
mymodule.factory("getMyDataService", function() {
  return getMyData;
};
mymodule.controller("myController", ["$scope", "getMyDataService", function ($scope, getMyDataService) {
  $scope.data = getMyDataService();
}]);
```

instead of this:

```
mymodule.controller("myController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = getMyData();
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you can now recover that data from anything that's injectable (i.e. another controller). However, you would likely refactor that service to be:

```
mymodule.factory('getMyDataService', function() {
    return function getMyData() {
        //returns some data...
    }
});
```

You wouldn't need that global function hanging out there, you'd want it encapsulated.

However, it's likely that if you're not happy with the idea that everything should be encapsulated and injectable via dependency injection, AngularJS may not be the framework for you. It takes JavaScript and moves it to a new realm. Don't force yourself down a path where you can't be effective.

The benefits of this framework are in its encapsulation and injection, it makes it very testable for one, but it also makes it modular in any fashion necessary.

Comment: And you cannot use `getMyData` in another controller directly?

Comment: It wouldn't be injectable. You have to inject it manually. Also saves a global function.

Comment: @devconcept of course you inject it manually, you inject everything manually, but a service is injectable into other concepts that can handle dependency injection (i.e. controller, service, and more).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I was answering the coment from zemkms. When you have something like dependency injection for free you don't throw that away for no reason. ;)

Comment: @devconcept I understand its benefits, and I was commenting the v1 of the answer that did not emphasize on that: "Because you can now recover that data from anything that's injectable". Which is obviously misleading, since you can "recover that data" also using a global name without problems.

Comment: @devconcept okay thanks! Next time make sure you mention the user in your comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use services to organize and share code across your app. 
There is no need to write the same function for each controller, When you write the same code more then once you violate the DRY principle.